# $\ x^4-7x^3+\left(13+m\right)x^2-\left(3+4m\right)x+m=0 $

Tags: polynomials, roots

> Given an equation:$$\ x^4-7x^3+\left(13+m\right)x^2-\left(3+4m\right)x+m=0 $$
>
> $\ x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4 $ are the roots,
>
> $\ x_1=2+3^{1/2} \land x_3=2x_4 $.
>
> What's the value of$\ m $?

I tried Horner's and Vieta's, and it looks like it should work with Vieta's, but I guess I'm missing something... The correct answer is $\ m=2 $.

Comment: Hint: factor it as $(x^2 - 4 x + 1) (x^2 - 3 x + m)\,$, then use the second condition.

Comment: See Irrational Conjugate Roots Theorem  here: http://mathweb.scranton.edu/monks/courses/ProblemSolving/POLYTHEOREMS.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $2+\sqrt3$ is a root, we can get a multiplier $x^2-4x+1$:
$$m(x^2-4x+1)+x(x^2-4x+1)(x-3)=0.$$
Now, in the equation $x^2-3x+m=0$ we need $x_3+x_4=3$,

which gives $x_3=2$ and $x_4=1$ and $m=2$.

Comment: `Since 2+√3 is a root ...` That's a good hunch, but it doesn't technically imply any particular multiplier unless you assume that $m$ is rational (so that $2-\sqrt{3}$ must also be a root).

Comment: @dxiv By $2+\sqrt3$ I tried to get $x^2-4x+1$ and it turns out.

Comment: The obvious is sometimes worth spelling out, since different people have different thresholds of "*obvious*".

Comment: @dxiv Sometimes I don't understand you. If you have a question then just ask it. If you have no questions and you understood all, why do you write it?

Comment: Didn't mean that to sound as nitpicking. You obviously answered OP's question, since they just accepted it, and presumably filled-in the blanks correctly. But this answer will be read many times over by later MSE users who'd come upon it while looking for similar questions, and the first line may leave them with the wrong idea that if $a+b\sqrt{c}$ is a root, then it's always safe to assume that $a-b\sqrt{c}$ is a root, too, which is of course *not* the case in general. `we can *guess* a multiplier` would work better than `we can *get* a multiplier` IMO.

Comment: @dxiv It is not entirely redundant to make your observation. The question should probably include $m$ integral or rational. As it stands there is nothing to stop me putting $x_3$ or $x_4$ equal to $2-\sqrt 3$.

Comment: @MarkBennet That is not a concern in *this* particular case since $x_3=2-\sqrt{3}$ gives $x_4=1+\sqrt{3}\,$ which is neither the double nor the half of the other root, but still it's a good observation to make.

Comment: @dxiv But it ought to be checked, I think.

Comment: @MarkBennet It ought to be checked, indeed. For a concrete example, take the same problem, only using the slightly different polynomial $$x^4 - (m + 4) x^3 + (4 m + 5) x^2 - (m + 16) x + 4=(x^2 - 4 x + 1) (x^2 - m x + 4)$$ Then there are $3$ solutions $m=8, \pm 3 \sqrt{2}$ and the first one comes precisely from the case you pointed out.